# WCF Invoke method only if certain condition is satisfied or else wait

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, async-await

I have a WCF service which implements a `ServiceContract`. For the sake of simplicity say the `ServiceContract` has only 1 method:

```
public interface ServiceContract
{
    String AddNewData(T arg1);
}
```

Here `AddNewData` can add data to `Database1` or `Database2` depending on
value of `arg1`. At certain point in time for a given value of `arg1` say `val1`, we are trying  to switch the storage from `Database1` to `Database2` and this process is time consuming (Say, it takes around a minute). During this period all the calls for `arg1 == val1`, should be suspended but we should still be able to perform `AddNewData` for all other values of `arg1` i.e. we should not be blocking the main thread.

I was thinking since `AddNewData` is the entry point for the call, I guess I want to be able to create `Task` which executes `AddNewData` but in case of `arg1 == val1`, I do not execute the Task but keep it suspended (in a not started state) and when the switch from `Database1` to `Database2` has taken place, I can run/start this suspended Task. 
I was thinking in terms of Task as I do not want to block the main thread to perform `AddNewData` for other values of `arg1`.

Now I am not sure how do I decide whether I want to start `AddNewData` or not before even entering the method for a given value of `arg1`. As per my understanding, I cannot suspend the execution of the `AddNewData` after entering the method as it would block the main thread. I looked into [IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  but couldn't figure out how to leverage this.

Anyone with any suggestions on how should I go about this. I am new to WCF and multithreading, so please excuse me if I am missing something straight forward here.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an async service contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceContract<T>
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> AddNewData(T arg1);
}
```

then on the server side

```
const int val1 = 10;

public class HelloService<int> : IServiceContract<T>
{
    public async Task<string> AddNewData(int arg1)
    {
      if(arg1==val1){
         // Poll to see if the database is ready
         // or use some other method that returns a 
         // a task when it is ready
         while(!(await DataBaseReady())
             await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
       }
       return "Got it"
    }
}
```

The above was shamelessly ripped off from

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/

and it contains a full example

Comment: How does the method `AddNewDataAsync` get the call from WCF? My main problem is sending the call to a method like `AddNewDataAsync` before `AddNewData` is called by WCF.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. AddNewDataAsync is calling AddNewData not the other way round.

Comment: In your code what code currently executes AddNewData? You say this is on the main thread. I'm assuming that it is in response to some GUI action?? Perhaps if you provide some more context than a single interface then it will be clearer what you are looking for.

Comment: A WCF service implements `ServiceContract` and hence contains an implementation for `AddNewData`. IIS invokes the WCF service and as per the contract will call `AddNewData` and not `AddNewDataAsync`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also the actual `ServiceContract` contains many methods similar to `AddNewData` say `GetData`, `UpdateData`, `DeleteData` etc. Would I need to implement a duplicate async method for each of those methods?

Comment: Ahh sorry. I don't really do any WCF programming. However a quick google search turned up what you want. I reworked my answer for you but follow the link and you should be right.